# Karabiner F1 to Launch Safari?

Tags: keybindings

What is the coding to program my F1 key to launch the Safari application using Karabiner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify private.xml and add:

```
<item>
   <name>F1 Safari</name>
   <identifier>f1_safari</identifier>
   <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F1, KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_APP_Safari</autogen>
</item>
```

Then enable it in *Change Key*. Depending on your settings (Consumer Keys or F1-F12 for the F-keys) in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard -> F-key behavior you may have to hit the fn-key also.

Answer (score 1):

In Karabiner Elements, add a complex modification rule to `/Users/username/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json`:

```
{
  "description": "Launch Safari (F1)",
  "manipulators": [
    {
      "from": {
        "key_code": "f1"
      },
      "to": [
        {
          "shell_command": "open -a '/Applications/Safari.app'"
        }
      ],
      "type": "basic"
    }
  ]
},
```

Then Add Rule and pick this one from the list.